# User group level reporting in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Maybe you can help me to find a solution for this.
I have a site in which there are users. These users are grouped into organizations. I would like to view the tracking events in Google Analytics at the organization level.

For example: User A registers through an email link. User A creates an organization and invites another User B into this organization. This User B also registers and joins the same organization. Then, User B makes a purchase on the site.

I would like to track this conversion at the organization level:
For instance: someone in the organization saw an email, and based on that, a purchase was made within the organization. Could you help me with how I could track this with Google Analytics 4? How could I put together these conversion charts?

(I'm trying this approach: After the user login the `user_id` will be set, and the `organization_id` of the user is also set as Google Analytics `user property`. On the Google Analytics site this organization_id property is defined as `Custom User Dimension`. But I don't know how to use this in Google Analytics and create a conversion chart.)